# Labels on tabs on bottom navigation not showing when back from background Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottomnavigationview

I have problem after update of Compose to version 1.6.1.
When the application backs from background, labels on bottom navigation are sometimes not visible before clicking on.
Has anyone had a similar problem?

I tried removing animations but it didn't change anything.

Comment: It's better if you add some code about your question and images of the event.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.